# External Table with one column CSV

Tags: sql, oracle, external-tables

I have the following CSV data and an external table definition. A CSV file with one column can be imported with this. I can read the data using the table, however as I choose them for reading, double quotes are imported before and after each row.

Please provide me some advice on how to import the data from the CSV file without using double quotes.

```
CREATE TABLE XXINT_IRS_EXT(
   "INVOICE_NUM" VARCHAR2 (100 BYTE)
)
ORGANIZATION EXTERNAL (TYPE oracle_loader
   DEFAULT DIRECTORY "OEB_INBOUND_DIR" ACCESS PARAMETERS (
       RECORDS DELIMITED BY NEWLINE
           BADFILE 'IRS14.bad'
           LOGFILE 'IRS14.log'
           SKIP 1
       FIELDS          
       TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"' 
       MISSING FIELD VALUES ARE NULL
   ) LOCATION ("INBOUND_DIR" : 'IRS14.csv')
) REJECT LIMIT UNLIMITED;
```

CSV sample data:

```
INV-2081272-05488243
INV-1656378-05427715
INV-1666200-05428937
INV-1688570-05432307
INV-3292506-00012864
INV-811613-05326087
```

Current output is as below.

```
"INV-2081272-05488243 
"
```

Expected output is as below.

```
INV-2081272-05488243
```

Answer (score 1):

This is Oracle 21cXE.

I don't have your directory (and don't feel like creating it), so I'll be using one of mine:

```
SQL> select directory_name From all_directories;

DIRECTORY_NAME
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
DATA_PUMP_DIR
EXT_DIR              --> I'll use this directory
```

No change in `CREATE TABLE` statement, except for the directory name (lines #5 and #13):

```
SQL> CREATE TABLE XXINT_IRS_EXT(
  2     "INVOICE_NUM" VARCHAR2 (100 BYTE)
  3  )
  4  ORGANIZATION EXTERNAL (TYPE oracle_loader
  5     DEFAULT DIRECTORY "EXT_DIR" ACCESS PARAMETERS (
  6         RECORDS DELIMITED BY NEWLINE
  7             BADFILE 'IRS14.bad'
  8             LOGFILE 'IRS14.log'
  9             SKIP 1
 10         FIELDS
 11         TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
 12         MISSING FIELD VALUES ARE NULL
 13     ) LOCATION ("EXT_DIR" : 'IRS14.csv')
 14  ) REJECT LIMIT UNLIMITED;

Table created.
```

CSV file contents:

```
SQL> $type c:\temp\irs14.csv
INV-2081272-05488243
INV-1656378-05427715
INV-1666200-05428937
INV-1688570-05432307
INV-3292506-00012864
INV-811613-05326087
SQL>
```

Select works OK and returns data *as is*, i.e. no *phantom* double quotes you reported:

```
SQL> select * from xxint_irs_ext;

INVOICE_NUM
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
INV-1656378-05427715
INV-1666200-05428937
INV-1688570-05432307
INV-3292506-00012864
INV-811613-05326087

SQL>
```

---

Please, edit the question and post your own SQL*Plus session which shows what you did and how Oracle responded.